# Как очистить DatePicker

Tags: c#, wpf

Выбранная дата в `DatePicker` биндится к свойству во ViewModel.

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding RegistrationDate}" />
```

Проблема в том, что при запуске программы дата отображается так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как очищать дату с поля ввода, если она равна значению по умолчанию?

Пробовал проверять через конвертер и возвращать `null`, но так не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помог [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23122007/6641468).

Оказывается нужно было работать со свойством `Text`. 
Повесил обработчик события на `SelectedDateChanged` и там обнуляю `Text`:

```
private void datePicker1_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (datePicker1?.SelectedDate == new DateTime())
    {
        datePicker1.Text = null;
        datePicker1.DisplayDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```